# CSS zoom to fit content without scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
const height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

const App = () => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', zoom: Math.min(width / 1200, height / 1200),}}>
    {[...Array(5).keys()].map(()=> (
      <div>
        {[...Array(5).keys()].map(() => (
          <div style={{ width: '250px', height: '250px' }}>text</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit j3zlzk68rv]

I need to fit all content into the viewport perfectly (i.e. at max width and height, no horizontal/vertical scrollbar).

In actual application, there are different components (images, custom components), so just setting `font-size: 1vw` etc is not sufficient.

The above solution does not work perfectly for all window width/height ratio (sometimes it's zoomed too much/too little).

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the body margin to 0 and also your width/height to 1250

```
document.body.style.margin = "0";
...
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', zoom: Math.min(width / 1250, height / 1250),}}>
```

Working demo:

[image: Edit w60l5qop2l]

Comment: I'm not able to set the height to 100% to fill the background color: https://codesandbox.io/s/6w7zkm6jlr. Any way to fix that?